# How to Put Files into the GitLab test without adding files to Src

Tags: java, file, continuous-integration, gitlab

Basically I have this problem:

I have a local folder that has multiples files, like CSV files for example,

I have a Java program that reads these files and do something with them.

I can't have these files in the Src paste on my project.

So, how to automatically copy this files into the GitLab CI test? Is there a solution for that?

How do I define that Folder for the GitLab to get the files from that folder?

I'm new in these CI/CD rules, so I'm kinda lost on what to do to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use the Maven convention and put them in src/test/resources folder.  They are committed to Git, available to your CI pipeline for testing, but not part of your deployed package.

Comment: @duffymo But what if the size of the files are too big? I would have to commit them anyway?

Comment: These csv files are part of your test cases?

Comment: Yes, the tests are directly linked to the CSV files

Comment: How big is too big?  They're your tests - if you don't think they should be committed, then don't commit them.

Comment: @duffymo Around 2 Gigabytes, but can I do tests without comitting it?

Comment: I'd wonder why you need lots of 2GB files to test.  If you don't put them in the repo, where will you put them so other developers and your Jenkins pipeline can use them?   Anything can be done.  Think through what's best for you.

Comment: IOne idea would be to set your own gitlab runner (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) . Then store your files into this runner and somehow configure your .gitlab-ci.yml to use them. Of course in this case the files will occupy disc space from the machine in which you will deploy the runner.

Comment: @SteveGr2015 This runner would be something "like" an FTP server? Is it too hard to use this Runner like this?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Well, actually with this approach you will store your files into you CI environment ,I posted some steps as an answer because was to long for a comment, I do not think that would be difficult if you are experienced on how to set, register and enable a gitlab ci runner.

Answer (score 0):

You may store your files into you CI environment so they will be there for any CI execution.

1. Install a new GitLab CI runner into one machine (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/)
2. Store your files into that machine,
3. Register this runner to your project (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#registering-a-specific-runner-with-a-project-registration-token)
4. Enable it for your pipeline through Settings --> CI/CD

After these steps your CI will run in the new runner. Gitlab CI will check out all of your source code in your runner machine and perform the CI steps by executing the commands that you have configured in .gitlab-ci.yml.
So you will be able to track the stored files by using the appropriated commands into the .gitlab-ci.yml .